# How to add an Emoji Picker to Angular App (Angular 12)

Tags: html, angular, emoji

I created a app clone Instagram to learn Angular. I wanna add a button while clicked will show a popup that contains icon list to use in comment.

[image: what i want]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution myself.

```html
 <div (keyup.enter)="postComment()" class="container_comment">
            <button (click)="isEmojiPickerVisible = !isEmojiPickerVisible;"><img src="assets/icons/smile-success-32.png"
                                                                                 width="28" height="28" alt=""></button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Add a comment..."
                   [(ngModel)]="comment"/>
            <emoji-mart class="emoji-mart" *ngIf="isEmojiPickerVisible" (emojiSelect)="addEmoji($event)"
                        title="Choose your emoji"></emoji-mart>
          </div>
```

and typeScript file add this

```
  public isEmojiPickerVisible: boolean;
  public comment: string = '';

  public addEmoji(event: { emoji: { native: any; }; }) {
    this.comment = `${this.comment}${event.emoji.native}`;
    this.isEmojiPickerVisible = false;
  }
```